# What are the values of A?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Question- Triangle $ABC$ has incenter $I$. Let points $X$, $Y$ be located on the line segments $AB$, $AC$ respectively, so that $BX\cdot AB = IB^2$ and $CY\cdot AC = IC^2$. Given that the points $X, I, Y$ lie on a straight line, find the possible values of the measure of angle $A$?

I have solved it and my answer is $60^{\circ}$. Are there any other possible values of $A$, because the question says "possible values of $A$"? Have I missed anything or any other values of $A$?

Please help.  And this question is from the Indian National Mathematics Olympiad - 1991.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the given $BI$ is a tangent line to the circle $(AIX)$, which gives $\measuredangle XIB=\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Similarly, $\measuredangle YIC=\frac{\alpha}{2}.$

Thus, since $X$, $Y$ and $I$ are collinear, we obtain:  $$\alpha=\frac{\beta}{2}+\frac{\gamma}{2}$$ or
$$2\alpha=180^{\circ}-\alpha$$ or $$\alpha=60^{\circ}.$$

Comment: So there is only one possible value, i.e. 60°?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: One More Question Please tell...   Question- Two circles C1 & C2 of radii a and b touch each other externally and they also touch a unit circle C internally. A circle C3 of radius r is inscribed to touch the circle C1 & C2 externally and the circle C internally. Find r in terms of a and b.

Answer - r=ab1−ab.       I have posted it in my profile, but no one responded...

Comment: I think it happens because you do not accept answers.

Comment: What? I don't accept answers! How to accept answers?

Comment: Use up arrow and V. All this under word: 1Answer.

Comment: I have clicked, it says your feedback has been recorded but doesn't showed in public, because your reputation is less than 15.